Will the C42 or other Ultralights break up on aerobatic manoeuvres?
There is a video here of an Ikarus C42 performing aerobatic maneuverers.
Now, I know the aircraft is not certified officially, but one of the commenters posted:

The reason these planes aren't rated for aerobatics is because their weight category prohibits acrobatics. Reality is that the power to weight ratio and material strength charactaristics of these planes is such that they're perfectly capable of it. GOOD LUCK getting the aircraft to pull enough G force to break itself, it literally won't go fast enough, you'd need a prolonged full-power dive.


The original aerobatic aircraft of the 20's were made of wood and doped linen, to think that a modern aircraft made of aluminium, nylon and carbon fibre are somehow weaker makes no sense.
A C42 doesn't weigh much, so to pull the 5+ G required to exceed the design specifications of it's wing spar and fixings would require extreme speeds. This display probably maxed out at 100kts, the aircraft would be fine.

Is this true? Is it actually a safe plane to do this in?

not an answer, but there's an old aviation adage which says "Don't do anything which you wouldn't want to form part of an accident investigation". ie/ "Pilot undertook high energy manoeuvres in an aircraft not certified for aerobatics...."

"to think that modern aircraft made of aluminium... are somehow weaker makes no sense" oops, I've just broken a strong aluminium foil with my bare hands...

An ask about the assumptions in the question: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/105023/does-weight-of-an-aircraft-affect-its-ability-to-pull-g

Seems like this might be a circular question, as the answer surely depends on what you define as "aerobatics" vs "safe manoeuvres" ?


The original aerobatic aircraft of the 20's were made of wood and doped linen, to think that a modern aircraft made of aluminium, nylon and carbon fibre are somehow weaker makes no sense.

The tacit assumption here is with two structures made of different materials, the structure made from stronger materials is always stronger, even if the structures are totally different. This is obviously incorrect. You can built an aerobatic plane out of wood just like you could build a plane that will fold under its own weight with aluminum.

A C42 doesn't weigh much, so to pull the 5+ G required to exceed the design specifications of it's wing spar and fixings would require extreme speeds. This display probably maxed out at 100kts, the aircraft would be fine.

Light weight makes it easier to pull more G's, not harder. That is why maneuvering speed increases with higher gross weight.
In any case, per its TCDS, the maneuvering speed is only 82 knots! Considering that its cruising speed at 75% power is listed as 94 knots, the statement that it would need a full-power dive to exceed acceleration limits is ridiculous.
Listening to people on the internet telling you that exceeding aircraft limitations is safe is a great way to get yourself killed.

Final sentence x100. Shouldn't even be listening to us,  but checking the actual people qualified to make the judgement.

Your commenter is a complete idiot. You posted it here because your BS-ometer was probably pinging at 11, but you weren't sure, and that's a good thing.
When it comes to structures, I can make, say a spar beam out of wood, aluminum, carbon, or fibreglass. I'll calculate the load it has to withstand, and I'll use a material cross sectional area that gives what's required to meet the tensile and compression strength required for the extreme limit case.
A wood spar cap made of sitka spruce might have a cross section of a square inch, whereas an aluminum cap will have a cross section of, say 1/4 square inch, and a carbon spar cap might be 1/3 of that. All will have the same strength. Wood has many structural advantages, one being immunity to fatigue.
So strength wise, material itself isn't an issue. The Icarus appears to have main spars of aluminum tube (probably 6061-T6) of some wall thickness, say .040", with a doubler tube inside to reinforce the strut connection where the bending loads are highest.
The C-42's handbook says it's good for +4/-2. This slightly better than Utility Category in certified airplanes, and is well short of aerobatic requirements, normally +6/-4. Those loads are normally a yield limit, the point at which you will bend something permanently. Coming completely apart, the ultimate limit, is another 50% fudge factor, so it should take at least 6G to make the wings fold up at gross weight, above maneuvering speed.
So its official numbers say it's definitely NOT safe for aerobatics, "legally" speaking. Most mild aerobatic maneuvers don't need more than 3Gs to complete, so in the hands of an expert who can keep the plane in limits, and at a reduced weight, it's certainly possible to do aerobatics safely, but you wouldn't want to unless you were an expert and were flying outside the published limits on purpose.
Keep in mind that there is a fair amount of fudge factor built into the structural selection to allow for wear and tear and assembly flaws, so the actual load required to bend the wings at gross weight might actually be 5 or 6Gs, but you can't bank on that.

Could a suitably trained pilot, perform certain aerobatic manoeuvres safely in a C42? Almost certainly yes.
Could performing certain manoeuvres in a C42, whether suitably trained or not, exceed the structural constraints of such an aircraft? Almost certainly, yes (although the same could be said for any aircraft, certified for aerobatics or not)
Should one perform aerobatic manoeuvres in any aircraft uncertified for such use? Almost certainly, no!

Will the C42 or other Ultralights break up on aerobatic manoeuvres?

The headline question is unanswerable beyond the above. Some manoeuvres don't even exceed 1g, and normal speed operating ranges. There's no reason that would break the aircraft as the structure wouldn't be any more affected than straight and level flight. All the above points about not doing it still apply.

Thanks for the answer Jamie, are any ultralights certified for aerobatics? *or can they be? I understand this is a separate question.

I don't see any reason why a fixed wing microlight couldn't be certified. Which ones are certified is some research and/or a question away

@Cloud We've been here before
